# Crash when trying to read from SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

Hey, I want to read from my Database, so I used this class so it copies my database to where it should be and then when I try to query it crashes:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    //The Androids default system path of your application database. 

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/omar.gestore/databases/";  
    private static String DB_NAME = "test1.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /** * Constructor * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources. * @param context */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1); 
        this.myContext = context; 
    }

/** * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database. * */

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){ 
            //do nothing - database already exist       
        }else{
            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into 
            // the default system path of your application so we are gonna be 
            // able to overwrite that database with our database. 
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            } 
        }
    }

    /** * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application. * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{ 
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false; 
    }

    /** * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled. * This is done by transfering bytestream. * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream 
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db 
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream 
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int length; 
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){ 
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length); 
        }

        //Close the streams 
        myOutput.flush(); 
        myOutput.close(); 
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database 
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null) myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor myQuery(String mquery){
        try
        {
            Cursor c =myDataBase.rawQuery(mquery,null);
            return c;
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            return null;
        }
        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database. 
        // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so itd be easy 
        // to you to create adapters for your views.
    }
}
```

and in my Main class:

```
DataBaseHelper myDatabase=new DataBaseHelper(this);

try {
    myDatabase.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
myDatabase.myQuery("SELECT * FROM adab;");
```

but it crashes because of Null Pointer.. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.

EDIT1: the crash is in this line: Cursor c =myDataBase.rawQuery(mquery,null); in myQuery function

Comment: show the line you get NPE at.

Comment: the crash is in this line: Cursor c =myDataBase.rawQuery(mquery,null); in myQuery function

Answer (score 0):

You have created the db and copied some data from the assets. But you haven't opened the copied database, so your `myDataBase` is `null`. Call `openDatabase()` after `myDatabase.createDataBase();`

Comment: I did call openDatabase but I still get the same NullPointerException =\